# .htaccess redirect to placeholder image for all images in a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

For every request that my server receives for an image in a specific folder, I need to serve up a placeholder image.

So - Every time a request is made for:

```
www.mysite.com/siteimage/scale/480/800/****/
```

I want my server to serve:

```
www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/placeholder.png
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule as your very first rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^siteimage/scale/480/800/ /wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/placeholder.png [L,NC,R=302]
```